# Google Cloud click to deploy wordpress is not working

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, lets-encrypt

Hello I need help with my wordpress site not loading. Currently I see a "site is taking too long to respond" error.

I am using a click-to-deploy wordpress instance in google cloud platform.
I also recently changed the size of the vm instance to E2 11GB, because google platform suggested it so I did exactly that. I think that could also be the problem.
I just recently setup certbot and I think it was installed correctly.

However, when I tried checking certbot renew dry run I got this...
`sudo certbot renew --dry-run`

```
Simulating renewal of an existing certificate for my-domain.com.mx and www.my-domain.com.mx
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: apache). The Certificate Authority reported these probl
ems:
  Domain: my-domain.com.mx
  Type:   connection
  Detail: Fetching http://my-domain.com.mx/.well-known/acme-challenge/cPuhyf6nQTtqjbDf7FJ6LtF9-4o109ogsQS4vAwNNfI: Tim
eout during connect (likely firewall problem)
  Domain: www.my-domain.com.mx
  Type:   connection
  Detail: Fetching http://www.my-domain.com.mx/.well-known/acme-challenge/lbwGM8-Wf_zmRV5vTAC0hEuEfBA5g7lfxG49VOKk3ZI:
 Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary Apache configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure
 that the listed domains point to this Apache server and that it is accessible from the internet.
Failed to renew certificate my-domain.com.mx with error: Some challenges have failed.
```

I pasted the actual response, I just replaced my actual domain with "my-domain".
As you can see, the renew command doesn't work :(.

I restarted apache like this `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

[These are the versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVGet.png) of everything that comes pre-intalled in the VM

Comment: Check if the public IP address changed. How big is your WordPress Site (visitors per day)? I am not aware of an E2 with 11 GB. What size did you select? An **e2-standard-2** or **e2-standard-4** is probably enough for a small site with MySQL.

Comment: @JohnHanley  The issue was fixed switching to an e2.stanrdar-4 with 16 gb ram. The website now loads perfectly. So im guessing 2 cores w 11 gb ram is not enough? Why does google recommend to lower it to that then?

Comment: I am not sure because I do not know what instance size you resized to.